# Display data from decimal to integer

Tags: c#

In database show column for "value" is 0.06 with datatype decimal(18,2).

How can i display in textbox value with value 6 Not 0.06?

I try change format to {0} but not successful. If used convert, How can i convert it?

```
<input type="text" runat="server" title="value" id="value" name="value"/>

protected string r_value = string.Empty;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (String.Format("{0}",Request.Params["value"]) != null) r_value =  String.Format("{0}",Request.Params["value"]);


    if (!IsPostBack)
        {          

            list_Detail();

        }
    }

 private void list_Detail()
    {
        try
        {
            BizeValue biz = new BizeValue();
            DataSet ds = biz.SPValue(r_ven);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            { 
                DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

                value.Value = String.Format("{0}", row["value"]) != null ? String.Format("{0}", row["value"]) : "";       
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base.scriptAlert("Raised Exception");
        }

    }
```

Comment: `0.06 * 100` would give `6`.

Comment: Can you give more examples of input and expected output? What would you expect the output to be for - .006,.006, .6, 6, 60,etc..

Comment: input: 0.00,0.10,0.06  and expected output: 0,10, 6 Do you know how to multiple by 100. If i multiple, will be error cannot apply type object and int.

Answer (score 2):

> How can i display in textbox value with value 6 Not 0.06?

If you try to cast 0.06 to an integer, you get 0.

It sounds like you are trying to convert a decimal value in the range 0.0 to 1.0 into a percentage in the range 0 to 100.  Just multiply your decimal value by 100 before casting to an integer.

Comment: Just multiply your decimal value by 100 before casting to an integer. Do you know how make it? i getting error.

Comment: Which variable exactly holds the double?  That's not entirely clear from your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast a string to Integer means you can use Int.TryParse(). But for 0.06 it will return the value as 0.

Comment: value.Value = String.Format("{0}",(Convert.ToDecimal(row["value"]))*100) != null ? String.Format("{0}",(Convert.ToDecimal(row["value"]))*100) : "";    if used this.. input from 0.06 will be output 6.00. How to convert become 6?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to declare variables.`One` is for convert value from database to numeric and multiply by 100 and convert `One` to string and keep it in `Two` or display.
Example:

```
decimal a;
string b;

a = decimal.Parse(<Value>)
a = a*100
b = a.ToString()
```